# Pre-Requirement for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am using JMeter and I want to use Jenkins now. Can you please say me what I need to install before installing Jenkins(I am using windows7, 64-bit system)? Kindly help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

This link

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins#InstallingJenkins-WindowsInstallation

will provide you all information concerning:

- Requirements: Unix Tools
- Install Jenkins as a Windows-Service (as a second step, after you have installed Jenkis)

First, you will need to install/start Jenkins. The WAR package is very easy to use:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

This will start Jenkins itself using Jetty. For Windows there is also a native package with a MSI installer.

Here you will find information if you want to use Jenkins in a existing container:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Containers